# forcing ffmpeg to drop audio at same rate it drops video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, concatenation

I've got a number of video files taken over several days on family vacation and I was hoping to combine these all into one 2 hour long file. Some of the source files are from an iPhone, some are from an Android phone. The video formats are either `.mp4` or `.mov`.

I'm using `ffmpeg` to combine the videos. Here is an example of the command I'm using to join the files for one day.

```
ffmpeg -i 20170904_083335.mp4 -i 20170904_174254.mp4 -i 20170904_174751.mp4 -i 20170904_195950.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v] [0:a] [1:v] [1:a] [2:v] [2:a] [3:v] [3:a] concat=n=4:v=1:a=1 [v] [a] " -map "[v]" -map "[a]" 20170904.mkv
```

My problem is that throughout the process `ffmpeg` will drop a video frame here and there. Throughout the process this can amount to hundreds or thousands of dropped frames (depending on the number of input files). My eyes can't visibly see the difference from the dropped frames, but I can definitely tell that the audio falls out of sync the longer the video is.

If `ffmpeg` could drop an audio "frame" at the same time it drops a video frame I feel like that would be perfect (thus the title of my question). I would then have exactly what I wanted. But I have no idea how to make it do that.

What I really want: one single video file where the audio stays in sync with the video throughout the entire duration of the video. If any of you has an idea of how to do that I'm all ears and would really appreciate the help.

Other things I've tried:

- [MP4Joiner](https://www.mp4joiner.org/en/)
- [Avidemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/)
- just adding all files as titles to a DVD and burning it

Things I have not tried but might try

- Just downloading Premiere Pro and throwing all files into a timeline and having it convert the whole thing.